# Get Bitmap from Lazy ListView Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I implemented lazy `ListView` adapter to display the images along with text from internet in `Listview`.Now I want to get the `Bitmap` of image when particular `ListItem` clicked and want to display it in a `ImageView`,But I am unable to get the `Bitmap` from the image.I am using this logic in `OnItemClickListener` for `ListView`:-

```
View imageView1 = listView1.getChildAt(position);
ImageView imageView3 = (ImageView) imageView1.findViewById(R.id.image);

Bitmap b;
imageView3.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
imageView3.buildDrawingCache();
b = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView3.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
car_image_detail.setImageBitmap(b);
```

But getting `NullPointerException` sometimes.Can anyone please help me out..?

Comment: check if bitmap!=null. then set imagebitmap to imageview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use my code. I am getting the image from the listview when a particular item is clicked and setting it to another imageview.

```
 //Code in listview itemclick listener
 final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
 final BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
 final Bitmap yourBitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
 show.setImageBitmap(yourBitmap); // show is another imageview
```